# React Redux Reducer does not retain other states

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to use stackoverflow api to make my first react redux project. I need to maintain a state like the following:

```
{
    selectedTag: reactjs,
    selectedSortOrder: activity,
    items:[]
}
```

My reducer is given below:

```
const initialState = {
  selectedTag: 'C#',
  selectedSortOrder: 'activity', items: []
}

function SelectTag(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECTTAG:
      //  console.log(state);
      return Object.assign({}, state, { selectedTag: action.selectedTag });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function SelectSortOrder(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECTSORTORDER:
      //console.log(state);
      return Object.assign({}, state, { selectedSortOrder: action.selectedSortOrder });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function ReceivePosts(state = { items: [] }, action) {
  switch
  (action.type) {
    case RECEIVESORTEDPOSTS:
    case RECEIVEPOST:
      console.log(state);
      return Object.assign({}, state, { items: action.items })
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ReceivePosts, SelectTag, SelectSortOrder })
```

And mapStateToProps is:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selectedTag = state.SelectTag.selectedTag;
  const items = (state.ReceivePosts.items);
  const tags = (state.ReceiveTags.tags);
  const selectedSortOrder = state.SelectSortOrder.selectedSortOrder;
  return {selectedTag, items, tags, selectedSortOrder};
}
```

I have 2 problems here:

a. State does not remember all the data. For eg. suppose I select the tag first and then get items, my state has only items. SelectedTag is not set in the state.

b. I am not sure why mapStateToProps needs the reducer name. Eg: const selectedTag = state.SelectTag.selectedTag;

Actually it should be state.selectedTag. But my code expects the reducer name "SelectTag" to fetch the state value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn’t look like you have your reducers hooked up right. Are you using combineReducers?

Comment: Yes Ryan, I am using combineReducers. Edited the post with the combineReducers code.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Try this code change**

```
const initialState = {
  selectedTag: 'C#',
  selectedSortOrder: 'activity', 
  items: []
}

function SelectTag(state = initialState.selectedTag, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECT TAG:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedTag: action.selectedTag
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function SelectSortOrder(state = initialState.selectedSortOrder, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SELECTSORTORDER:
      return {
        ...state,
        selectedSortOrder: action.selectedSortOrder
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

function ReceivePosts(state = { items: [] }, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case RECEIVESORTEDPOSTS:
    case RECEIVEPOST:
      return {
        ...state,
        items: action.items
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ ReceivePosts, SelectTag, SelectSortOrder });
```

**2.** **I am not sure why mapStateToProps needs the reducer name. Eg: const** `selectedTag = state.SelectTag.selectedTag;`

Its because when you use `combinereducers`, you are combining **multiple slices** of data, then you need to specify the **slice** from which you want to fetch the data.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ 
    receivePosts = ReceivePosts, 
    selectTag = SelectTag, 
    selectSortOrder = SelectSortOrder 
});
```

**Issue:** You have not configured your **initialstate** properly, you are using the same **initialstate** in `SelectTag` and also in `SelectSortOrder`, if the initial state is same then why do you need two reducers?

Comment: Changing the reducer code as above shows all the three items as part of the state. But it shows with default values.

Eg: {selectedTag: "javascript", selectedSortOrder: "activity", items: Array(0)}

when selectedTag is javascript. But selectedSortOrder was previously changed to "votes". that value is not retained. 

Regd mapStateToProps - my assumption is that state is a global object which can change in any reducer and can be referred in app.js. Why should I refer to the reducer type as I am not changing the same state value in multiple reducers. Please clarify.

Comment: You are using the same initial state in both reducers, if the state is the same then you don't need two reducers. you can change the initial state on the reducers if you want to have two.

Comment: I changed the initial state on the reducers as you mentioned. The log gives the state as 

{0: "C", 1: "#", selectedTag: "php"}
{0: "a", 1: "c", 2: "t", 3: "i", 4: "v", 5: "i", 6: "t", 7: "y", selectedSortOrder: "votes"}

where _c#_ was my default value for selectedTag and _php_ the chosen value and _activity_ the default value for selectedSortOrder and _votes_ the chosen value.

Comment: The reason state splits the default value into single character after a tag/sort order is selected is bcos the key of the default item is missing. Hence object.assign or ...state, breaks the default value and appends the newly selected value. 

changing the above code to 

`SelectTag(state = {selectedTag:initialState.selectedTag}`

worked.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't configured your reducers correctly. The initialState is assigned to all of your reducers which isn't required

```
 const initialState={   
    selectedTag:'C#',  
    selectedSortOrder:'activity',
    items:[]
 }

function SelectTag(state = initialState.selectedTag, action){  
  switch(action.type){ 
     case SELECTTAG:
       return action.selectedTag
     default:
       return state;   
  }
}

function SelectSortOrder(state = initialState.selectedSortOrder, action){  
  switch(action.type){
     case SELECTSORTORDER:
       return action.selectedSortOrder
     default:
       return state;
    }
}

function ReceivePosts(state = {items:[]}, action){   
   switch(action.type){
       case RECEIVESORTEDPOSTS:
       case RECEIVEPOST:
         console.log(state);
         return Object.assign({}, state, {items:action.items})
       default:
         return state
     }
 }

const rootReducer = combineReducers({ReceivePosts, SelectTag, SelectSortOrder})
```

---

And in mapStateToProps you would use it like

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const selectedTag = state.SelectTag;
  const items = (state.ReceivePosts.items);
  const tags = (state.ReceiveTags.tags);
  const selectedSortOrder = state.SelectSortOrder;
  return {selectedTag, items, tags, selectedSortOrder};
}
```